# r-cran artifactory repository setup

Tags: r, artifactory, cran

Has anyone successfully setup a CRAN repository in Artifactory?

I have setup the local, remote, and virtual repos, but I am having trouble pushing an R package successfully to Artifactory:

```
install.packages('mypackage', repos='https://my.artifactory/artifactory/cran')
```

This is the error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://my.artifactory/artifactory/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': status was '401 Unauthorized'
```

Part of the issue might be the expected default layout of a CRAN repo does not match my simple repo, and part may be that I have no idea how to supply user credentials for Artifactory authentication when I try to upload a package.

If anyone has helpful ideas, or can point me to a blog post I would appreciate it.

NOTE: I have also installed the recommended Artifactory plugin: `expirePackagesMetadata.groovy`

Comment: What layout did you use?  You could consult this: https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/custom-repos.html for details on what is expected

Comment: I used the `simple` layout as recommended by JFrog. Basically it acts as a generic repo, and I can upload and download R packages using curl. However then I need to install those packages from the local filesystem, instead of directly from Artifactory.

Comment: I guess that is the intended functionality for now, until Artifactory fully supports the package meta-data that the PACKAGES & PACKAGES.gz provide.

Comment: I have followed this guide and it worked: https://www.jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-proxy-a-cran-repo-with-artifactory/